# Returning PersistentCollection not ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Not sure what I did.. 
But now my Entity is returning "PersistentCollection" when I try to get the related atribute.

Until yesterday it was returning "ArrayCollection".
I cant use "foreach" in PersistentCollection, so I get errors..

No idea what I touched to make this.. What I have to check?

Comment: You can use foreach just fine on a persistent collection as it implements array access http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.2/class-ArrayAccess.html - please post examples of where your code is failing.

Comment: @4You Did you find a solution ? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is use Presistent Collection with methods of Collection. 
For Example, you can get elements of Collection by such way:

```
$array = $presistentCollectionObject->getValues();
foreach ($array as $obj) {
 dump($obj);
}
```

**Note** that if you dump PresistentCollection object directly, element ArrayCollection (which is contained inside) will be empty.